# Syslog-ng duplicate log lines

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, syslog-ng

I have a very annoying situation concerning apache access/error logs on a remote log server.

Webserver:
Stock apache logging with:

```
ErrorLog "|/usr/bin/logger -p local7.err -t www.sitename.com"
CustomLog "|/usr/bin/logger -p local7.info -t www.sitename.com" "combined"
```

rsyslog is configured as follows:

```
local7.info @log.remote.lan
local7.err @log.remote.lan
```

So far so good. All logs end up at the remote log server. On that server I have syslog-ng configured as follows:

```
options {
        long_hostnames(off);
        flush_lines(0);
        use_dns(no);
        use_fqdn(no);
        owner("root");
        group("adm");
        perm(0644);
        dir_perm(0755);
        stats_freq(0);
        bad_hostname("^gconfd$");
        create_dirs(yes);
        keep_hostname (yes);
};
destination hosts_acc {
        file("/var/log/remote/${newmsghdr}/$R_YEAR/$R_MONTH/$R_DAY/access.log");
};
destination hosts_err {
        file("/var/log/remote/${newmsghdr}/$R_YEAR/$R_MONTH/$R_DAY/error.log");
};
filter f_access {
        message("GET|POST|OPTIONS|HEAD");
};
filter f_error {
        message('\[error\]');
};
log {  
        source(s_lan);
        rewrite(r_msghdr);
        filter(f_access);
        destination(hosts_acc);
        flags("final");};
log {  
        source(s_lan);
        rewrite(r_msghdr);
        filter(f_error);
        destination(hosts_err);
        flags("final");
};
```

Both logs work fine. But... the error log is inserted twice in the logfile. When I set the webserver to log to a local file the error appears only once in that file. Any clues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're sending the log lines twice, because of these lines in rsyslogd.conf:

```
local7.info @log.remote.lan
local7.err @log.remote.lan
```

When you specify info, that means that info **and all higher priorities** will be sent, not only info. Since err has a higher priority than info, you can remove the second line, so the log will only be sent once.