# syslog-ng duplicate log message

Tags: linux, logging, syslog, syslog-ng

Not duplicate of [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/409231/syslog-ng-duplicate-log-lines) question because that one uses rsyslog on client whereas I use syslog-ng on both sides.

I have a syslog-ng instance on both the client and the server and for whatever reason the there are repeated log lines in the server log.
The logs are sent into the mail facility.

```
2021-12-18T21:01:44+01:00 192.168.1.11 [warning] Warning: this is a test
2021-12-18T21:01:44+01:00 192.168.1.11 [err] TEST ERROR
2021-12-18T21:01:44+01:00 192.168.1.11 [crit] not a crit cond actually
2021-12-18T21:01:44+01:00 192.168.1.11 [alert] wee woo wee woo
(duplicated lines start here)
2021-12-18T21:01:44+01:00 192.168.1.11 [warning] Warning: this is a test
2021-12-18T21:01:44+01:00 192.168.1.11 [err] TEST ERROR
2021-12-18T21:01:44+01:00 192.168.1.11 [crit] not a crit cond actually
2021-12-18T21:01:44+01:00 192.168.1.11 [alert] wee woo wee woo
```

My syslog-ng client config

```
@version: 3.33
@include "scl.conf"
#
# /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf
#

options {
  stats_freq (0);
  flush_lines (0);
  time_reopen (10);
  log_fifo_size (10000);
  chain_hostnames (off);
  dns_cache (no);
  use_dns (no);
  use_fqdn (no);
  create_dirs (no);
  keep_hostname (yes);
  perm(0640);
  group("log");
};

source src {
  system();
  internal();
};

destination d_authlog { file("/var/log/auth.log"); };
destination d_syslog { file("/var/log/syslog.log"); };
destination d_cron { file("/var/log/crond.log"); };
destination d_daemon { file("/var/log/daemon.log"); };
destination d_kernel { file("/var/log/kernel.log"); };
destination d_lpr { file("/var/log/lpr.log"); };
destination d_user { file("/var/log/user.log"); };
destination d_uucp { file("/var/log/uucp.log"); };
destination d_mail {
  syslog("raspi" port(8000) transport("tcp"));
  #file("/var/log/mail.log");
};
destination d_news { file("/var/log/news.log"); };
destination d_ppp { file("/var/log/ppp.log"); };
destination d_debug { file("/var/log/debug.log"); };
destination d_messages { file("/var/log/messages.log"); };
destination d_errors { file("/var/log/errors.log"); };
destination d_everything { file("/var/log/everything.log"); };
destination d_iptables { file("/var/log/iptables.log"); };
destination d_acpid { file("/var/log/acpid.log"); };
destination d_console { usertty("root"); };

# Log everything to tty12
destination console_all { file("/dev/tty12"); };

filter f_auth { facility(auth); };
filter f_authpriv { facility(auth, authpriv); };
filter f_syslog { program(syslog-ng); };
filter f_cron { facility(cron); };
filter f_daemon { facility(daemon); };
filter f_kernel { facility(kern) and not filter(f_iptables); };
filter f_lpr { facility(lpr); };
filter f_mail { facility(mail); };
filter f_news { facility(news); };
filter f_user { facility(user); };
filter f_uucp { facility(uucp); };
filter f_ppp { facility(local2); };
filter f_debug { not facility(auth, authpriv, news, mail); };
filter f_messages { level(info..warn) and not facility(auth, authpriv, mail, news, cron) and not program(syslog-ng) and not filter(f_iptables); };
filter f_everything { level(debug..emerg) and not facility(auth, authpriv); };
filter f_emergency { level(emerg); };
filter f_info { level(info); };
filter f_notice { level(notice); };
filter f_warn { level(warn); };
filter f_crit { level(crit); };
filter f_err { level(err); };
filter f_iptables { match("IN=" value("MESSAGE")) and match("OUT=" value("MESSAGE")); };
filter f_acpid { program("acpid"); };

log { source(src); filter(f_acpid); destination(d_acpid); };
log { source(src); filter(f_authpriv); destination(d_authlog); };
log { source(src); filter(f_syslog); destination(d_syslog); };
log { source(src); filter(f_cron); destination(d_cron); };
log { source(src); filter(f_daemon); destination(d_daemon); };
log { source(src); filter(f_kernel); destination(d_kernel); };
log { source(src); filter(f_lpr); destination(d_lpr); };
log { source(src); filter(f_mail); destination(d_mail); };
log { source(src); filter(f_news); destination(d_news); };
log { source(src); filter(f_ppp); destination(d_ppp); };
log { source(src); filter(f_user); destination(d_user); };
log { source(src); filter(f_uucp); destination(d_uucp); };
#log { source(src); filter(f_debug); destination(d_debug); };
log { source(src); filter(f_messages); destination(d_messages); };
log { source(src); filter(f_err); destination(d_errors); };
log { source(src); filter(f_emergency); destination(d_console); };
log { source(src); filter(f_everything); destination(d_everything); };
log { source(src); filter(f_iptables); destination(d_iptables); };

# Log everything to tty12
#log { source(src); destination(console_all); };
```

The server config

```
@version: 3.27
@include "scl.conf"

# Syslog-ng configuration file, compatible with default Debian syslogd
# installation.

# First, set some global options.
options { chain_hostnames(off); flush_lines(0); use_dns(no); use_fqdn(no);
      dns_cache(no); owner("root"); group("adm"); perm(0640);
      stats_freq(0); bad_hostname("^gconfd$");
};

########################
# Sources
########################
# This is the default behavior of sysklogd package
# Logs may come from unix stream, but not from another machine.
#
source s_src {
       syslog(ip("0.0.0.0") port(8000) transport("tcp"));
};

# If you wish to get logs from remote machine you should uncomment
# this and comment the above source line.
#
#source s_net { tcp(ip(127.0.0.1) port(1000)); };

########################
# Destinations
########################
# First some standard logfile
#
template recv {
    template("${ISODATE} ${HOST} [${LEVEL}] ${MESSAGE}\n");
};
destination d_auth { file("/var/log/auth.log"); };
destination d_cron { file("/var/log/cron.log"); };
destination d_daemon { file("/var/log/daemon.log"); };
destination d_kern { file("/var/log/kern.log"); };
destination d_lpr { file("/var/log/lpr.log"); };
destination d_mail { file("/var/log/${YEAR}-${MONTH}.log" template(recv)); };
destination d_syslog { file("/var/log/syslog"); };
destination d_user { file("/var/log/user.log"); };
destination d_uucp { file("/var/log/uucp.log"); };

# This files are the log come from the mail subsystem.
#
#destination d_mailinfo { file("/var/log/mail.info"); };
#destination d_mailwarn { file("/var/log/mail.warn"); };
#destination d_mailerr { file("/var/log/mail.err"); };

# Logging for INN news system
#
destination d_newscrit { file("/var/log/news/news.crit"); };
destination d_newserr { file("/var/log/news/news.err"); };
destination d_newsnotice { file("/var/log/news/news.notice"); };

# Some 'catch-all' logfiles.
#
destination d_debug { file("/var/log/debug"); };
destination d_error { file("/var/log/error"); };
destination d_messages { file("/var/log/messages"); };

# The root's console.
#
destination d_console { usertty("root"); };

# Virtual console.
#
destination d_console_all { file(`tty10`); };

# The named pipe /dev/xconsole is for the nsole' utility.  To use it,
# you must invoke nsole' with the -file' option:
#
#    $ xconsole -file /dev/xconsole [...]
#
destination d_xconsole { pipe("/dev/xconsole"); };

# Send the messages to an other host
#
#destination d_net { tcp("127.0.0.1" port(1000) log_fifo_size(1000)); };

# Debian only
destination d_ppp { file("/var/log/ppp.log"); };

########################
# Filters
########################
# Here's come the filter options. With this rules, we can set which 
# message go where.

filter f_dbg { level(debug); };
filter f_info { level(info); };
filter f_notice { level(notice); };
filter f_warn { level(warn); };
filter f_err { level(err); };
filter f_crit { level(crit .. emerg); };

filter f_debug { level(debug) and not facility(auth, authpriv, news, mail); };
filter f_error { level(err .. emerg) ; };
filter f_messages { level(info,notice,warn) and 
                    not facility(auth,authpriv,cron,daemon,mail,news); };

filter f_auth { facility(auth, authpriv) and not filter(f_debug); };
filter f_cron { facility(cron) and not filter(f_debug); };
filter f_daemon { facility(daemon) and not filter(f_debug); };
filter f_kern { facility(kern) and not filter(f_debug); };
filter f_lpr { facility(lpr) and not filter(f_debug); };
filter f_local { facility(local0, local1, local3, local4, local5,
                        local6, local7) and not filter(f_debug); };
filter f_mail { facility(mail) and not filter(f_debug) and not host("localhost"); };
filter f_news { facility(news) and not filter(f_debug); };
filter f_syslog3 { not facility(auth, authpriv, mail) and not filter(f_debug); };
filter f_user { facility(user) and not filter(f_debug); };
filter f_uucp { facility(uucp) and not filter(f_debug); };

filter f_cnews { level(notice, err, crit) and facility(news); };
filter f_cother { level(debug, info, notice, warn) or facility(daemon, mail); };

filter f_ppp { facility(local2) and not filter(f_debug); };
filter f_console { level(warn .. emerg); };

########################
# Log paths
########################
log { source(s_src); filter(f_auth); destination(d_auth); };
log { source(s_src); filter(f_cron); destination(d_cron); };
log { source(s_src); filter(f_daemon); destination(d_daemon); };
log { source(s_src); filter(f_kern); destination(d_kern); };
log { source(s_src); filter(f_lpr); destination(d_lpr); };
log { source(s_src); filter(f_syslog3); destination(d_syslog); };
log { source(s_src); filter(f_user); destination(d_user); };
log { source(s_src); filter(f_uucp); destination(d_uucp); };

log { source(s_src); filter(f_mail); destination(d_mail); };
#log { source(s_src); filter(f_mail); filter(f_info); destination(d_mailinfo); };
#log { source(s_src); filter(f_mail); filter(f_warn); destination(d_mailwarn); };
#log { source(s_src); filter(f_mail); filter(f_err); destination(d_mailerr); };

log { source(s_src); filter(f_news); filter(f_crit); destination(d_newscrit); };
log { source(s_src); filter(f_news); filter(f_err); destination(d_newserr); };
log { source(s_src); filter(f_news); filter(f_notice); destination(d_newsnotice); };
#log { source(s_src); filter(f_cnews); destination(d_console_all); };
#log { source(s_src); filter(f_cother); destination(d_console_all); };

#log { source(s_src); filter(f_ppp); destination(d_ppp); };

log { source(s_src); filter(f_debug); destination(d_debug); };
log { source(s_src); filter(f_error); destination(d_error); };
log { source(s_src); filter(f_messages); destination(d_messages); };

log { source(s_src); filter(f_console); destination(d_console_all);
                    destination(d_xconsole); };
log { source(s_src); filter(f_crit); destination(d_console); };

# All messages send to a remote site
#
#log { source(s_src); destination(d_net); };

###
# Include all config files in /etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/
###
@include "/etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/*.conf"
```

Comment: Hi, it's not clear where do the duplicate messages appear: is it in the d_mail destination files on your server? If yes, then are they also duplicated on the client side (when you enable the commented file destination in the client's d_mail)?

Comment: @RobertFekete The issue seems to happen only on the server. The client logs fine.

Comment: Weird. Is there anything in your /etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/ directory that could add another source or log statement?